# Show more than one result from JOIN with if statement

Tags: php, mysql, join, conditional-statements, fetch

I have this JOIN, that gets me more than on result:

```
at.tipo AS atividade,
at.data AS datacadastro,
at.user AS usercadastro, 

LEFT JOIN atividades at
        ON (at.produto = '$produto')
        AND (at.tipo = 'cadastra' OR at.tipo = 'revisado')
```

And I have: `if string = 'cadastra' shows something`, `if string = 'revisado' shows something else`.

```
<?php

    if ($row['atividade'] == 'cadastra') {  
        echo '<div id="user-img">';
        echo '<img src="http://'.$row['imguser'].'"/></div>';   
        echo '<div id="user-cadastro" class="greytxt">';                    
        echo 'Cadastrado por <br>' .$row['usercadastro']. '<br>em ';
        echo $row['datacadastro']. '</div>';
    }

?>

<?php

    if ($row['atividade'] == 'revisado') {  
        echo '<div id="user-img">';
        echo '<img src="http://'.$row['imguser'].'"/></div>';   
        echo '<div id="user-cadastro" class="greytxt">';                    
        echo 'Cadastrado por <br>' .$row['usercadastro']. '<br>em ';
        echo $row['datacadastro']. '</div>';
    } 

?>
```

The problem is, it's showing just the first result, and not all.

How can I display all results?

**EDIT:**

I have this JOIN inside a big query, that give me other important rows.
But I just want one result for this principal query (`WHERE = $produto`), and want more results from my JOIN table.

```
$rows = $result->num_rows;  

for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j) {
    $result -> data_seek($j);
    $row = $result->fetch_array (MYSQLI_ASSOC);

?>
```

My result should be this, but JOIN shows just row 'cadastra'.
[image: My result should be this, but JOIN shows just row 'cadastra'.]

Comment: Don't you have if fetch instead of while fetch ?

Comment: edited, Im using fetch and for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$result->fetch_array (MYSQLI_ASSOC)` inside a `while` loop

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array (MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

 if ($row['atividade'] == 'cadastra')
        {   
  echo '<div id="user-img">';
  echo '<img src="http://'.$row['imguser'].'"/></div>'; 
  echo '<div id="user-cadastro" class="greytxt">';                  
  echo 'Cadastrado por <br>' .$row['usercadastro']. '<br>em ';
  echo $row['datacadastro']. '</div>';
            } ?>

 <?php if ($row['atividade'] == 'revisado')
        {   
  echo '<div id="user-img">';
  echo '<img src="http://'.$row['imguser'].'"/></div>'; 
  echo '<div id="user-cadastro" class="greytxt">';                  
  echo 'Cadastrado por <br>' .$row['usercadastro']. '<br>em ';
  echo $row['datacadastro']. '</div>';
            }
}
```

Comment: should I remove the 'for'?

Comment: @Bibiana yes, replace your for code with the code of my answer

Comment: Nothing changed, just showing one result :/
`$result = $conn ->query ($query);
  
  if (!$result) die ($conn->error); 
    
    
       while ($row = $result->fetch_array (MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ ?>`

Comment: @Bibiana in this case your query only return one row, try your query in phpmyadmin and see the result

Comment: Adrian, I'm sure there's more than one result in this JOIN table with these specifications.

Comment: @Bibiana please, test your query in phpmyadmin and let my know the result

Comment: How can I show you? With a print?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pqln06m5buul1iu/print-mysql.jpg

Comment: @Bibiana Is not the same query, I can't see the JOIN

Comment: The main query is huge. https://www.dropbox.com/s/p2dyt3yk27jmito/mainquery.jpg Shows just one row.

Comment: @Bibiana in this case you should edit your questoin with your table definition (sql query) and the output that you expect